# How to navigate from one component to another in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

How can I navigate from one lwc component to another or From one app page(which contain's the first component) to another App Page containing the other component by passing parameters?

Comment: what did you try so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation